# Java11 and JMockit 1.43 Java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError happened when Jmockit mockup System.currentTimeMillis

Tags: java, jmockit, java-11

I am trying to mock System.currentTimeMillis using jmockit1.43 using below code

```
private static class SystemMock extends MockUp<System>{
    @Mock
    public static long currentTimeMillis() {
        return ourMockCurrentTime;
    }
}
```

But I am getting below error when running my test:

```
00:01:37.658110 [.]     [junit] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis()J
00:01:37.658185 [.]     [junit]     at java.base/java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis(Native Method)
00:01:37.658188 [.]     [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.run(JUnitTestRunner.java:544)
00:01:37.658228 [.]     [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.launch(JUnitTestRunner.java:1196)1548910897.658231: 
00:01:37.658280 [.]     [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.main(JUnitTestRunner.java:1041)
```

Is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: I believe this is not a complete stack trace still. Please share the complete details for a better understanding of the cause.

Comment: I have updated with full stacktrace

Answer (score 2):

The only way to avoid the issue is to apply the mockup ("fake") for the whole test run, by setting the `fakes` system property (`-Dfakes=your.fully.qualified.name.SystemMock`) in the command line or Maven/Gradle test execution configuration.

The underlying reason is that the `java.lang.System` class requires a call to an internal "`registerNatives()`" method (or "`initIDs()`" in certain other classes), in order for the original definition of the class (after it's done being faked) to be restored. Other classes in the JDK which also have `native` methods don't have such a method. JMockit dropped the call in recent versions for JDK 9+ compatibility, and also because it was a hack only made necessary because of JDK idiosyncrasies (which should be solved within the JDK itself).